# babel-preset-react-app NODE_ENV production v test

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I am using preset `react-app` to build my component and publish for other projects to use. When built with env `production` it transpiles the code but still keeps `import` and `export` and not convert it to `exports.` and `require`. However when I pass env `test` it transpiles everything including `import` and `export`. This is what I expected `production` to do. I am having problems writing jest tests where my component is used as it expects `node_modules` to have fully transpiled code. Does any one know why and have a possible fix for this? Can I use `test` for my publish build to work around this.

```
SET NODE_ENV=production&& babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files
```